# How to use tf.where with convolutions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create a graph that splits into several other graphs at after certain point according to classification results. I thiought `tf.cond` or `tf.where` might be right to use but im not sure how.

It is impossible to copy here all of my code but I created a small segment that illustrates the issue.

```
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
GPU_INDEX = 2

net_class = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],[0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1],[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]) # 3,0,1,2,3
classes = tf.argmax(net_class, axis=1)
cls_0_idx = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(classes, 0)))
cls_3_idx = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(classes, 3)))

cls_0 = tf.gather(params=net_class, indices=cls_0_idx)
cls_3 = tf.gather(params=net_class, indices=cls_3_idx)

params_0 = tf.constant([1.0,1,1,1])
params_3 = tf.constant([3.0,3,3,3])


output = tf.stack([tf.nn.conv1d(cls_0, params_0, 1,  padding='VALID'), tf.nn.conv1d(cls_3, params_3, 1,  padding='VALID')])

sess = tf.Session()
cls_0_idx_val = sess.run(output)

print(output)
```

Here I tried to extract the indexes of the input that classifies as 0 or 3 and use different variables to multiply them for the output (shared weights for each class, this is why I use the convolution).

I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'conv1d/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: ?, [1,4].
```

I understand why I get the error ( because `tf.where` doesn't "know" its size) but the question is how do I fix it? (the classes are not equal and may even be empty in my "real" problem as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should

1. setup `axis` to `1` in `tf.squeeze`
2. change `tf.nn.conv1d` to simple multiply
3. change `tf.stack` to `tf.concat`

then you will have something like this:

```
net_class = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1],[0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1],[0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]) # 3,0,1,2,3
classes = tf.argmax(net_class, axis=1)
cls_0_idx = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(classes, 0)), -1)
cls_3_idx = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(classes, 3)), -1)

cls_0 = tf.gather(params=net_class, indices=cls_0_idx)
cls_3 = tf.gather(params=net_class, indices=cls_3_idx)

params_0 = tf.constant([1.0,1,1,1])
params_3 = tf.constant([3.0,3,3,3])
output = tf.concat([cls_0 * params_0, cls_3 * params_3], axis = 0)
```

Comment: Yes! this works! but I  just realized that I need to maintain the order of the original array `net_cls` in `output` (now it just stacks them). How can I do that?

Comment: I figured it out: `output = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(net_class))
output = tf.scatter_nd_add(output, indices=tf.expand_dims(cls_0_idx, -1), updates=cls_0 * params_0)
output = tf.scatter_nd_add(output, indices= tf.expand_dims(cls_3_idx,axis=-1), updates=cls_3 * params_3)`

Comment: Sorry for the many comments - the `tf.scatter_nd_add()` is not right here . It doesnt update the model correctly, `tf.scatter_update()` doesnt have a gradient so im still suck on how to reorder the data to match the original ( and have gradients propegate correctlu)